# THREE: how to get an object, it is nearly CylinderGeometry but top side not circle

Tags: three.js

I would like to ask about Three.js. How to get an object, it is nearly CylinderGeometry but one side (top or bottom) not circle. it can be an elip, rectangle,any closed shape...

It is similar Loft command in SolidWork soft.

How any one can help me on this.

Thanks,
Hung

Comment: (Welcome to Stack Overflow! …where salutations and _thanks_ are considered clutter to avoid. Your post will be read times and again: please do your best regarding spelling, spacing, … see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) There's no need to repeat the first tag in the title of the question: it is automatically put in the title of the page generated.) What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a shape that is a "prism" that smoothly shifts at one end to the other between two arbitrary shapes is not a simple operation.

Three.js has some primitives (such as the CylinderGeometry you mention), but nothing that can do this for you itself. Given the complexity of this task it might be preferable to generate your shape in actual 3d Modeling software (i.e. [Blender3D](https://www.blender.org/)) and then importing it into your scene.

Comment: Hi Hectate,

Thanks for your reply.

But i need program  can modify values at running time.
So there is no way at current time, right ? Maybe anyone can help on later revision....i will wait...

Thanks,
Hung

Comment: The only way I envision this would be to draw your shapes and then iterate over the vertices to devolve one shape into the other. If you have a circle with 30 segments and you want to devolve it into a square (4 segments) you would have to drop X number of segments per iteration. Connecting the vertices between iterations is the challenging part. Which vertices connect where? Which ones need to merge? I can imagine ways of doing it but they're not simple.

Comment: Hi Hectate, 

Do you have an example for build a arbitrary surface then I can study it.
I expect a hero develop the LoftGeometry for everyone :)

Thanks,
Hung

Comment: Given that you mentioned a Cylinder first, I would recommend looking closely at the way three.js creates that primitive in the source code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/CylinderBufferGeometry.js

I've not done anything that creates faces, but I did do some code that created a line shape into a spiral out of a series of vertices. Feel free to steal from that code if desired as well :https://jsfiddle.net/87wg5z27/100/

Comment: Hi Hectate,

Thanks for your info. I got the error when opening link https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/CylinderBufferGeometry.js.

I would like to show you the picture that the surface i would like to build.  I'm many thanks you when you have similar exmaple or way to build it.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Sc2qvKsKJ-N1R6bjAyU3E0azA

It is similar Cylinder but one sdie is other shape.

Thanks,
Hung

Comment: If you have any example to build custom surface, please show to me.  

Thanks,
Hung

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a 2d shape and then extrude it to a 3d object using THREE.js. For example see code below to create a rounded box geometry. In similar way you can create an ellipse and extrude it.

```
// create a square box
const l = 100, w = 100, h = 100, roundRadius = 5, bevelRadius = 10;
var shape = new THREE.Shape();

shape.moveTo( -l/2 + roundRadius, -w/2 );
shape.lineTo( l/2 - roundRadius, -w/2 );
shape.absarc ( l/2 - roundRadius, -w/2 + roundRadius, roundRadius, -Math.PI/2, 0, false );
shape.lineTo( l/2, w/2 - roundRadius );
shape.absarc ( l/2 - roundRadius, w/2 - roundRadius, roundRadius, 0, Math.PI/2, false );
shape.lineTo( -l/2 + roundRadius, w/2 );
shape.absarc ( -l/2 + roundRadius, w/2 - roundRadius, roundRadius, Math.PI/2, Math.PI, false );
shape.lineTo( -l/2, -w/2 + roundRadius );
shape.absarc ( -l/2 + roundRadius, -w/2 + roundRadius, roundRadius, Math.PI, -Math.PI/2, false );

// extrude it 
var extrudeSettings = { amount: h, bevelEnabled: true, bevelThickness: bevelRadius, bevelSize: bevelRadius, bevelSegments: 20 };

const geo = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
```